# Sign Up Form onclick/for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a sign up page where a user clicks on an input tag and 
a span tag appears to the right specifying the requirements

Ex. User clicks on input and span says "Username must be at least __ characters long"

I set the span in the css file as display:none

then in my javascript file contains the code below:

```
//lists all the input tags in an array
var signUpInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("signUpInputs");

for(var index=0; index < signUpInputs.length;index++ ){
    alert("hi"); **//Just to check if function works and it does**
**//The following code below doesn't though. In the console it says "Uncaught    
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined "**

    signUpInputs[index].onclick=function(){
 document.getElementsByClassName("errorFormMessage")[index].style.display="inline-   
    block";
}
}//end of for loop
```

I'm not sure why it says that it can't read the property style of undefined because I believe I defined it when I used document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: ... to the person who suggested it as an onload issue and deleted their comment... I'm assuming that the loading part is fine, because otherwise the result of `document.getElementsByClassName("signUpInputs")` wouldn't contain those elements either (unless somehow the script is triggered between the processing of two adjacent HTML elements, which typically could only happen with a `defer` tag (with odds of one in a million or so), or if the OP for some strange reason put this script tag between one of the form elements and the span tag which followed it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("errorFormMessage")[index].style.display = ...
```

This is the line of code which now produces the error `Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`, and the error means that are missing element(s) of the class `errorFormMessage` for one/some of the corresponding `signUpInputs` elements.

Your loop is indexed by iterating through the result of `document.getElementsByClassName("signUpInputs")`, but it is trying to access an `errorFormMessage` element that does not exist. This means that now there must be at least one `signUpInputs` element that does not have a corresponding `errorFormMessage` element.

Ensure that your HTML code has exactly a one-to-one correspondence of elements of class `errorFormMessage` to your `signUpInputs` elements, i.e., for each and every one of your elements with the class `signUpInputs`, you need an element of the class `errorFormMessage`, with no extra elements of either type existing elsewhere within your HTML page, unless they also have a matching pair of both elements.

You should also make sure that your script is run after your relevant HTML elements have been added to the DOM, but I am assuming this is not the problem because that problem would manifest itself before your even started the loop (you would get an empty or incomplete result from `getElementsByClassName("signUpInputs")`).

Comment: Thanks :) This really helped. It was an accurate analysis of the problem.